# animating width of “distribute matrices” with float input is possible?

Tags: animation-nodes

[image]
I’m practicing animation nodes and 
I would like to animate width of “distribute matrices” by float input or parameter itself.

---

additional edit

i would like to adjust entire matrix size, like keyframing width parameter of distribute matrices. and Time info can animate, but I think it will be complicated to set.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to adjust scale entire matrix ?

Comment: Why dont you connect it with a math node set to multiply and the frame info to the "Distribute Matrix" inputs ?

Comment: thank you for comments. I edited my question.  yes I want to adjust scale entire matrix. and frame info worked to animate by frame, but   to calculate the value at the frame will be bit complicate for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I found "Animate Float" and could get preferable result.